# CSS float right without changing order?

Tags: html, css

There are some similar questions like this already, but none of those fixes worked for me. I want to float a `<li>` menu to the right, but I can't get it to do it correctly.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="topnav"><ul class="topnavlinks"><li class="menu-474 first"><a href="/" title="Home page">Home</a></li>
 <li class="menu-540 active-trail active"><a href="/our-company" title="" class="active">Our company</a></li>
 <li class="menu-541"><a href="/news_blog" title="">Blog</a></li>
 <li class="menu-930"><a href="/faq" title="Frequently Asked Questions">FAQ</a></li>
 <li class="menu-900 last"><a href="/contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#topnav { width:100%; height:14px; background:#b8b8b8; border-bottom:1px solid #989898; }
.topnavlinks { width:980px; margin:0px auto; }
.topnavlinks ul { float:right;  }
.topnavlinks li { float:left;  }
.topnavlinks a { color:#fff; text-decoration:none; padding:0px 27px; }
```

Currently it doesn't float to the right at all, and with some other variations I have gotten it to float right, only with reversed order.

Comment: so? write you html reversed :)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your code?

Comment: User position:absolute;right:0

Comment: what do you want clear and can u post image  ......

Comment: @slash197: it is not always acceptable to reverse the order of the html elements (think, screen readers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding additional container

**HTML**

```
<div id="topnav"><div class="cont"><ul class="topnavlinks"><li class="menu-474 first"><a href="/" title="Home page">Home</a></li>
 <li class="menu-540 active-trail active"><a href="/our-company" title="" class="active">Our company</a></li>
 <li class="menu-541"><a href="/news_blog" title="">Blog</a></li>
 <li class="menu-930"><a href="/faq" title="Frequently Asked Questions">FAQ</a></li>
 <li class="menu-900 last"><a href="/contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.cont { width:980px; margin:0px auto; }
#topnav { width:100%; height:14px; background:#b8b8b8; border-bottom:1px solid #989898; }
.topnavlinks ul { float:right;  }
.topnavlinks li { float:left;  }
.topnavlinks a { color:#fff; text-decoration:none; padding:0px 27px; }
```

Comment: I added an extra `float:right` to `.cont` and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Hi I found another solution using `display:flex` and `justify-content:flex-end`

So in the original question, instead of:

```
.topnavlinks ul {
  float:right;  
}
```

Change it into the following:

```
ul.topnavlinks {   
  display: flex;   
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}
```

It will make the navigation float right without changing order

Comment: Best solution ever! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This one should be approved

Answer (score 0):

Remember there is horizontal padding of 27px.
This puts the menu to the right:

```
 #topnav { width:100%; height:14px; border-bottom:1px solid #989898; text-align:right; }

.topnavlinks { margin:0px auto; display:inline; float:right;}

.topnavlinks ul { float:right; text-align:left; }

.topnavlinks li { display:inline; text-align: left;}

.topnavlinks a { color:#fff; text-decoration:none; padding:0px 27px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/gVnrM/
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gVnrM/)

[This one](http://jsfiddle.net/gVnrM/2/)

Comment: It's reversed ;-). Home is on the right of the menu, instead of the left.